# How do i add these elements to a string

Tags: c++, string

I am having trouble adding these elements to the `trans` string. The id is a `int`, name is a `string`, cost, price, and profit are all `double`.

i thought that just using '+' would work but i just get

> "invalid operands of types'const char*' and'const char[8]' to
>   binary'operator+'

```
string transaction::toString(){
   string trans = "ID: " + getId() + ",Name: "+ getName()+ ",Cost: "+ getCost() + ", Price: "+getPrice() + ", Profit: "+getProfit();
   //trans += getId();
   return trans;
}
```

the expected result should look like this:
ID: (id value), Name: (name string), Cost: (cost value), Price: (price value), Profit: (profit value)

Comment: Sometimes it's just about working through it.
What are all the operands? Does the `"ID : "`, which is a `const char*` and the return from  `getId()` do `+` ?

Comment: the getId() and the others are the getters, the getId() generates a random number for the transaction id. The purpose of this is just to return the trans string for another class to print out which i know the other class works because i tested it with a regular string.

Comment: @Someone the purpose of the functions isn't important in this context, but, if the random number that `getId()` generates is anything but a `std::string` (and possibly some other corner case) I think you're out of luck.

`"ID: "` decays into a `const char*` and the `+` is just adding to the memory address. It will not end well. ... and @Muhammed Gül showed you how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `#include <sstream>` and do this:

```
string transaction::toString()
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << "ID: " << getId() << ",Name: " << getName() << ",Cost: " << getCost()  << ", Price: " << getPrice()  << ", Profit: " << getProfit();
   return ss.str();
}
```